# Generating gibberish Java resource bundle for i18n testing

Tags: java, internationalization, translation

I've got a resource bundle for a Java application containing English phrases. For testing purposes, I'd like to generate a gibberish (Swedish Chef, or other nonsense language) resource bundle based on the English one, so that it's still readable but clearly not English. Something similar to the [Google "Bork" localisation](https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=xx-bork).

Is anyone aware of a simple tool that will do this?

## Edit

Ideally I'd like to be able to run the resource bundle property file through this tool, and have it generate a new property file with modified text, for example:

```
foo.bar=Hello, world
```

to

```
foo.bar=Halloo, Woorld
```

Comment: Do you want truly random gibberish or should the actual content *somehow* represent the "real" text?

Comment: Ideally I'd like it to represent the "real" text.

Answer (score 3):

Lorem Ipsum: http://www.lipsum.com

Comment: This lipsum generator has two problems. First, it doesn't generate Java resource bundles. Second, it doesn't reflect the actual text. I've clarified the question.

Comment: Alternative suggestion: Convert each word of the original text to its Soundex representation.  Then reverse the Soundex to get a different word that would generate the same Soundex.  Not difficult to program.

Answer (score 0):

The [Dialectizer](http://www.rinkworks.com/dialect/) has a Swedish Chef option which translates web pages: [see here](http://www.rinkworks.com/dialect/dialectp.cgi?dialect=bork&url=http://news.bbc.co.uk).

Here's [another option](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/jbc/home/chef.html), which also includes a link to the translator source.